# Как в inline функции вывести массив?

Tags: c++, c

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
inline string print(vector<string> arr){
    for(auto i : arr){
        cout<<i<<endl;
    };
    return; //что можно вставить в return, кроме 0?
};
int main() {
    vector<string> array={"1", "2", "3"};
    cout<<print(array);
    cout<<"Your choice:"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Есть вот такой код, где я пытаюсь вывести массив с помощью функции inline, но для этой функции нужен return, как-то можно убрать этот return или возвращать какой-то символ, чтобы не переходить на следующую строку, или как-то выводить массив через return? Я пытался, что-то сделать, вот к чему пришел: "return 0" - заканчивает программу, а мне это не нужно, "return a", где a="", перекидывает на новую строчку.

Comment: Чтобы вывести массив там не надо ничего возвращать и пытаться использовать бессмысленное возвращаемое значение.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вызывать функцию, пишущую в конкретный поток можно было и без `cout<<`, так как вы написали себе функцию `print`, в котором поток жёстко обозначен. На самом деле давно все делают вывод в поток используя оператор `<<` и возвращют этот-же поток, чтобы можно было вызвать печать *других* объектов туда-же.

```
ostream & operator<<(ostream & f,vector<string> const &arr){
    for(auto i : arr){
        f<<i<<endl;
    }
    return f;
}
int main() {
    vector<string> array={"1", "2", "3"};
    vector<string> array2={"a", "b", "c"};
    cout<<array<<array<<array2<<array2;
}
```

*Задав `operator<<` как `inline` никак не изменит фактический код, так как код с циклом увеличивает размер кода и компилятор откажется это сделать как `inline`.*

Answer (score 3):

Вы немного странную вещь делаете. Нужно определиться, где Вы именно хотите сделать вывод. У Вас же внутри функции организован вывод:

```
 for(auto i : arr){
        cout<<i<<endl;
    };
```

Если нужно выводить именно из неё, то просто делаем тип возвращаемого значения `void` и никакие `cin << print()` в `main` не нужны.
Т.е. буквально должен быть такой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

inline void print(vector<string> arr) 
{
    for (auto i : arr)
    {
        cout << i << endl;
    }
}

int main() 
{
    vector<string> array = { "1", "2", "3" };

    print(array);

    cout << "Your choice:" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Либо же делать вывод непосредственно из `main`, путем возвращения из функции `print()` строки, но это, как мне кажется, странное решение. Более того, тогда ни название функции, ни сама функция `print()` не будет иметь никакого смысла